# response time API gateway and Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I need to build api service that would return response with in milliseconds. I am inclined towards using API gateway powered by Lambda.Say I keep my lambda warm by invoking it every 5 minutes or so. Is it slower to use API gate way powered by lambda instead of traditional web service hosted on ec2? Does any one have any experience on this matter?

Comment: Well I couldn't agree more to what Brennan has said. In short, if you want a super fast API, don't use Lambda. You can go for it if performance is not important for you. Even though you keep them warm due to the cold start issue, it will still be affected from the delayed starts if you get multiple concurrent requests. Also please check how much extra you pay for running an EC2 instance vs invoking a lambda every 5 minutes. Finally, both of these options have its ups and downs, question is what is more important to you.

Comment: A good article https://hackernoon.com/im-afraid-you-re-thinking-about-aws-lambda-cold-starts-all-wrong-7d907f278a4f

Answer (score 2):

Your mileage may vary, but after building a bunch of lambda functions to serve some needs I had, I ended up moving most of them back to EC2 in order to get acceptable performance. IN both cases they still use API gateway in front of them.

I still use Lambda for some functions where super-fast response is not needed, but for me it wasn't fast enough.

You should build a few examples and test yourself however, as I said - you results may be different than mine.